# What is the point of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin http header?

Tags: http, http-headers, xss

I have difficulties in seeing the point of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin http header.

I thought that if a client (browser) gets a "no" from a server once, than it will not send any further requests. But chrome and firefox keep sending requests.

Could anyone tell me a real life example where a header like this makes sense?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should contain a list of origins which are "allowed" to access the resource.

Thus, determining which domains can make requests to your server for resources.

For example, sending back a header of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` would allow all sites to access the requested resource.

On the other hand, sending back `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example.com` will allow access only to http://foo.example.com.

There's some more information on this over at the [Mozilla Developer Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control)

**For example**

Let's suppose we have a URL on our own domain that returns a JSON collection of Music Albums by Artist. It might look like this:

```
http://ourdomain.com/GetAlbumsByArtist/MichaelJackson.json
```

We might use some AJAX on our website to get this JSON data and then display it on our website.

But what if someone from another site wishes to use our JSON object for themselves? Perhaps we have another website `http://subdomain.ourdomain.com` which we own and would like to use our feed from `ourdomain.com`.

Traditionally we can't make cross-domain requests for this data.

By specifying other domains that are allowed access to our resource, we now open the doors to cross-domain requests.

Comment: thanks! yes i have read the mozdev article already. but i still dont understand. could you give a real-life example where foo.example.com would make sense.

Comment: I've added a brief example. I hope that clarifies things for you and if not, perhaps you have a more specific question?

Comment: Glad this makes sense @clamp Hit the accept button if you feel this answered your question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

CORS implements a two-part security view of cross-origin. The problem it is trying to solve is that there are many servers sitting out there on the public internet written by people who either (a) assumed that no browser would ever allow a cross-origin request, or (b) didn't think about it at all.

So, some people want to permit cross-origin communications, but the browser-builders do not feel that they can just unlock browsers and suddenly leave all these websites exposed. To avoid this, they invented a two-part structure. Before a browser will permit a cross-origin interaction with a server, that server has to *specifically* indicate that it is willing to allow cross-origin access. In the simple cases, that's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. In more complex cases, it's the full *preflight* mechanism.

It's still true that servers have to implement appropriate resource access control on their resources. CORS is just there to allow the server to indicate to browsers that it is aware of all the issues.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it address the reason CORS exists in the first place. CORS is basically a "NO TRESPASSING" sign, but facing the wrong direction. It's only purpose is to retroactively protect badly written servers from requests from mainstream browsers. CORS provides absolutely zero security, and only serves to obfuscate cross-site request patterns.